# How do I get my tabs to go 100% across the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alignment, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to get my jQuery tabs to go all the way across the top and line up on the left and right side with the edges, I tried doing fixed widths but it doesn't seem to want to cooperate that way. Does anyone know how to do this? Also it keeps jumping around when you click on a tab, I saw it's because they are hiding the border of the content by moving the tab down over the border... is there anyway to connect the tabs to the content without moving the tab itself and creating that jumping?

http://jsfiddle.net/fun6faos/2/

```
<style>
.tabs-all {
    width: 830px;
    font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.etabs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.tab-container .panel-container {
    background: #fff;
    border: solid #c2c2c2 1px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.panel-container {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tab1 {
    width: 209px;
    display: inline-block;
*display:inline;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: none;
}
.tab2 {
    width: 233px;
    display: inline-block;
*display:inline;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: none;
}
.tab3 {
    width: 124px;
    display: inline-block;
*display:inline;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: none;
}
.tab4 {
    width: 207px;
    display: inline-block;
*display:inline;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: none;
    font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.tab1.active, .tab2.active, .tab3.active, .tab4.active {
    background: #fff;
    padding-top: 6px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    border-color: #c2c2c2;
    border-top: 5px solid #70bf47;
    border-right: solid 1px #c2c2c2;
    border-left: solid 1px #c2c2c2;
}
.tab1 a, .tab2 a, .tab3 a, .tab4 a {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 2em;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #464646;
    font-weight: 600;

}
.tab1 a:hover, .tab2 a:hover, .tab3 a:hover, .tab4 a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tab1 a.active, .tab2 a.active, .tab3 a.active, .tab4 a.active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #464646;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
      $('#tab-container').easytabs();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tabs-all">
<div id="tab-container" class='tab-container'>
  <ul class='etabs'>
    <li class='tab1'><a href="#tabs1">What is Community Solar?</a></li>
    <li class='tab2'><a href="#tabs2">Why Clean Energy Collective?</a></li>
    <li class='tab3'><a href="#tabs3">How it Works?</a></li>
    <li class='tab4'><a href="#tabs4">Community Solar Benefits</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class='panel-container'>
    <div id="tabs1">
      <h2>TITLE</h2>
      <p>Information</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs2">
      <h2>TITLE</h2>
      <p>Information</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs3">
       <h2>TITLE</h2>
      <p>Information</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs4">
       <h2>TITLE</h2>
      <p>Information</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a cue from Bootstrap's tabs, we can apply table layout properties with CSS:

```
li.tab {display: table-cell; width: 1%;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/fun6faos/15

This example results in uniform tab widths. To have tabs sized somewhat proportionately to their text labels, remove the width property:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/fun6faos/17

A note on your use of classes... A class, by definition, is a set of properties applied to multiple elements. When you're incrementing classes, you're using them wrongly. You should never have a list of elements in your CSS that have indexed numbers. I've stripped all such craziness out of your code.

Comment: Oops. Had a bad fiddle link in there.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to make the tabs different widths depending on the length of the content within them? Like How it works is much smaller than Why Clean Energy Collective and doesn't need as much width, so that none of the text wraps? And also how to make the bottom border on the tabs not show up when it's active so that it looks like one piece?

Comment: See my updated answer for your tab width question. Considering the state of the web, with responsive behavior the new norm and the wide range of devices, I wouldn't spend too much time fretting over that.

Comment: I meant I don't want the border-top on the content to show up underneath the tab when it's active, if that makes sense. So it looks like the active tab is in front the other tabs? Maybe setting a z-index on the tab so that it shows up above the content box and blocks out the line between the content and the tabs?

Comment: I see that it does in Firefox. Chrome and IE11 are fine.

Comment: Yah I am using Firefox 31.0, I saw it doesn't show up in the other browsers, but it still does in Firefox.

Comment: The `top` property only applies to absolutely-positioned elements. You'll need to find another way to push the active tab down over the panel border. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top

Answer (score 1):

You need to zero out the margins. Add this to your CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. Perhaps you misunderstood.